# querying to check for integer values in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to execute this query in rails app

```
   Video.where("category= 'film' AND grant = 1").order('created_at DESC').page(params[:page]).per_page(10)
```

here grant stores an integer value.

and I am getting following error

```
    Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'grant = 1) ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0' at line 1: SELECT  `videos`.* FROM `videos`  WHERE (category= 'film' AND grant = 1) ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is with grant. GRANT is a reserved word in MySql. You should use back-ticks around them.

```
Video.where("category= 'film' AND `grant` = 1").order('created_at DESC').page(params[:page]).per_page(10)
```

will do the job i guess. Refer [**Reserved Words**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

Comment: A more Rails-ish implementation would use `where(category: "film", grant: 1)`.

Comment: what if we want to use OR instead of AND ?

Answer (score 4):

Try this ..

```
@videos=Video.where(:category => 'film',:grant => 'yes' ).order('created_at DESC').page(params[:page]).per_page(10)
```

Comment: thanks, it worked for me... but i have no clue why other queries is not working.

Comment: also i changed :grant => 'yes' to :grant => '1'. since my "grant " stores integer value.

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
Video.where("category = ? AND `grant` = ?", "film", 1).order('created_at DESC').page(params[:page]).per_page(10)
```