# Rails query boolean MySQL error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Doing any one of these:

```
notifications.where("read = 'true'")
notifications.where("read = '1'")
notifications.where("read = true")
notifications.where("read = 1")
```

results in the error:

> Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'read = 'true')

However, this works just fine:

```
notifications.where(:read => true)
```

Any idea why this could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**read** is mysql reserved keyword you need to use back-ticks  around your column name

```
notifications.where(" `read` = true")
```

Not familiar with ruby but you can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17718868/querying-to-check-for-integer-values-in-ruby-on-rails) to enclose the column with back-ticks

### [**Mysql Reserved Words**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html)

Comment: Oh wow ok. Is it safe to use it still or should I user another name?

Comment: Best practice is use  the meaning full column name like `user_read` or `notification_read` so it has the minimal chance to produce such type of errors and you can easily use the column names without back-ticks